# DialogStack.Forward doesnt work where in Context.Forward works

Tags: c#, bots, botframework

I have a scenario in which i want to forward context to another dialog using Context.Forward and it works perfectly. Now if i update code to fetch dialog stack and use DialogStack.Forward, it results in Stack is Empty exception. Any pointer to this issue will be highly appreciated.

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, message))
{
var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
await botData.LoadAsync(default(CancellationToken));
var stack = scope.Resolve<IDialogStack>();

// DialogStack.Foward doesn't work 
await stack.Forward(new FeedbackDialog(FeedbackContext.CreateLead.ToString(), this.GetService<IResourceManager>()), this.ResumeAfterFeedbackDialog, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity(), CancellationToken.None);
}

// Context.Forward works
await context.Forward(new FeedbackDialog(FeedbackContext.CreateLead.ToString(), this.GetService<IResourceManager>()), this.ResumeAfterFeedbackDialog, context.Activity.AsMessageActivity(), CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: Where/when are you trying to call stack.Forward?  Why not use context.Forward?  Please elaborate a bit on what you are trying to do.

Comment: In my scenario, i have an invoke Activity Type, which i have to handle separately i.e. outside of a dialog context. At the end, i want to call a dialog to handle few more stuffs. As i am handling invoke activity outside of dialog context, and i need to use a dialog for last operation, i need to either get context from somewhere or do this through DialogStack.

Comment: Can you just call Conversation.SendAsync(message, () => new FeedbackDialog());  ?

Comment: i can not use Conversation.SendAsync as i already have 2 dialogs in stack when invoke is called. So i cant do that (actually i tried this option and it failed). Any other way?

Comment: i removed the resume after method and got the code to forward context to new dialog. But if i don't specify the resume after method i can not complete the dialog context. Any idea how to get around it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the AlarmBot sample that does something similar:

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot/Models/ExternalEvent.cs

Please try something like this:

Edit:

```
using (var scope = DialogModule.BeginLifetimeScope(Conversation.Container, activity))
{
    var token = new CancellationToken();
    var botData = scope.Resolve<IBotData>();
    await botData.LoadAsync(token);
    var task = scope.Resolve<IDialogTask>();

    var child = new TestDialog();                        
    var interruption = child.Do(new ResumeAfterCall().ResumeAfter);

    try
    {
        task.Call(interruption, null);
        await task.PollAsync(token);
    }
    finally
    {
        await botData.FlushAsync(token);
    }
}

        [Serializable]
        public class ResumeAfterCall
        {
            public async Task<IMessageActivity> ResumeAfter(IBotContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
            {
                return await result as IMessageActivity;                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Eric. I have already seen this sample. This doesn't help me much, first i want to use Forward and second the resume after method is specified as null, but i need to have a resume after method specified here.

Comment: I've edited my answer to enable providing a ResumeAfter method.